# how many virtual machine can be created in a machine with 16GB RAM

Tags: virtual-machine

i want to create no. of virtual machines with Ubuntu operating system. I want to install hadoop, spark, yarn, cassandra, mongodb etc big data tools on each one of it. so, how many virtual machine can be created on a single machine with 16GB RAM?
other info. is given below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IexFY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your software requirement maximum of 2 virtual machines can be created..that too if you are not using cloudera-manager services

Comment: can you elaborate your answer how to calculate

Comment: this is my assumption -8gb -2 vms | os -2gb,yarn-1Gb,spark-1gb,Gb,HIve 1Gb,cassendara,MongoDB -1 GB each..